# SNMP4J request timeout with SNMPv3

Tags: java, snmp, snmp4j

I am looking to make a Java program that manages some switches. For now, I am just trying to get a single value from the switch. I have a working example that uses SNMPv2, however, my attempts at SNMPv3 always result in no response (Error: Agent Timeout). I have, however, tried it using the "snmpget" command with the exact same values, and it outputs the expected results. So in principle, SNMPv3 should work with my current setup.

The non-functional SNMPv3 code:

```
public static void getAdminCycleTimeNumeratorv3() throws IOException
{
    String  ipAddress  = "10.1.0.4";
    String  port    = "161"; 
    String  oidValue  = "1.3.111.2.802.1.1.30.1.2.1.1.8.1.1";  
    int     snmpVersion  = SnmpConstants.version3;
 
    TransportMapping transport = new DefaultUdpTransportMapping();
    Snmp snmp = new Snmp(transport);

    USM usm = new USM(
        SecurityProtocols.getInstance(),
        new OctetString(MPv3.createLocalEngineID()),
        0
    );

    SecurityModels.getInstance().addSecurityModel(usm);

    transport.listen();

    // Set the target
    UserTarget target = new UserTarget();
    target.setAddress(GenericAddress.parse("udp:10.1.0.4/161"));
    target.setRetries(2);
    target.setTimeout(2000);
    target.setVersion(SnmpConstants.version3);
    target.setSecurityLevel(SecurityLevel.AUTH_PRIV);
    target.setSecurityName(new OctetString("snmpuser"));

    // Set the security settings
    snmp.getUSM().addUser(
        new OctetString("snmpuser"),
        new UsmUser(
            new OctetString("snmpuser"),
            AuthMD5.ID,
            new OctetString("foo#Bar0815"),
            PrivDES.ID,
            new OctetString("foo#Bar0815")
        )
    );

    // Create PDU
    PDU pdu = new ScopedPDU();
    pdu.add(new VariableBinding(new OID(oidValue))); 
    pdu.setType(PDU.GET);

    System.out.println("Sending SNMP Request");
    ResponseEvent response = snmp.get(pdu, target);

    // Process Agent Response
    if (response != null)
    {
        PDU responsePDU = response.getResponse();

        if (responsePDU != null)
        {
            int errorStatus = responsePDU.getErrorStatus();
            int errorIndex = responsePDU.getErrorIndex();
            String errorStatusText = responsePDU.getErrorStatusText();

            if (errorStatus == PDU.noError)
            {
                System.out.println("Snmp Get Response = " + responsePDU.getVariableBindings());
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Error: Request Failed");
                System.out.println("Error Status = " + errorStatus);
                System.out.println("Error Index = " + errorIndex);
                System.out.println("Error Status Text = " + errorStatusText);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Error: Response PDU is null");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Error: Agent Timeout");
    }
     
    snmp.close();
}
```

The same code with SNMPv2c and a CommunityTarget instead of a UserTarget does work just fine. So I suspect that the culprit is my user or target management, but I can´t seem to find a solution. It works via the net-snmp console tool, so my switch is configured properly.

Edit: the working snmpget command is:

```
snmpget -v3 -l AuthPriv -u snmpuser -a MD5 -A "foo#Bar0815" -x DES -X "foo#Bar0815" 10.1.0.4:161 1.3.111.2.802.1.1.30.1.2.1.1.8.1.1
```

Edit 2: For anyone wondering, the problem can be solved by creating a SecurityProtocols instance first, and then calling

```
SecurityProtocolsInstance.addAuthenticationProtocol( new AuthSHA());
SecurityProtocolsInstance.addAuthenticationProtocol( new AuthMD5());
```

Before passing the instance to the USM.

Comment: What is the snmpget command that works? You must make it part of the question.

Comment: I am talking about the snmpget command provided by the net-snmp package.


snmpget -v3 -l AuthPriv -u snmpuser -a MD5 -A "foo#Bar0815" -x DES -X "foo#Bar0815" 10.1.0.4 1.3.111.2.802.1.1.30.1.2.1.1.8.1.1

Comment: wow, Java doesn't make it easy. I looked at one other example and noticed that it had `transport.listen()` after the `snmp.getUSM().addUser()`, maybe try that. Would it be possible to post a packet capture? I normallly use `tcpdump` with the `-X` flag to print the packet contents in hex

Comment: Unfortunately, that change didn´t resolve the issue. Since I use udp for communication with the switch, I used this command for a packet capture:

sudo tcpdump -i ens82f0 udp and dst 10.1.0.4 -w udpdump.pcap

It captured only a single package, and the result doesn´t appear readable to me:

ÔÃ²¡                Fÿdew5 g   g   ìtº­q'ÐP™ü
× E  Yß¬@ @FÙ
  
 Ýˆ ¡ Ee0;0N¶„ ÿÿ0      0      0

Comment: use `-X` instead of `-w <file>` and it will print it in hex on the screen

EDIT: I notice you have `dst 10.1.0.4` in your filter, which will filter out any response from the switch. I'm not an expert on filters, but see if you can capture the traffic going both ways

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, but I did actually find a solution - since SNMP4J 3.X.X it is required to activate the security protocols for the SecurityProtocols instance with SecurityProtocols.addAuthenticationProtocol( new AuthSHA()); and
SecurityProtocols.addAuthenticationProtocol( new AuthMD5()); before passing the instance to the USM. This solved all of my issues.